# Property works fine on one machine but it gives an error on another

Tags: c#, properties, c#-6.0

I've got the code with property written like this:

```
public bool Expanded { get => expanded; set => expanded = value; }
```

on one machine it works fine but on another it is all red highlighted ('not all code paths return a value')

It works fine when I rewrite it like this:

```
public bool Expanded
{
    get { return expanded; }
    set { expanded = value; }
}
```

but I don't want to rewrite it.

On both machines I use .NET Framework 4.7.1

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Are both machines running the same version of Visual Studio? Are either using Resharper?

Comment: What's the c# version on the "non working" machine?

Comment: On working machine there is VS pro 2017, non working - VS express 2015 and C# 6.0

Comment: Have you considered trying VS 2017 Express on the non-working machine? Have you considered using `public bool Expanded { get; set; }` instead?

Comment: Are you sure both versions have the same runtimes installed

Comment: Yeah, working computer has C# 7, the second one has C# 6. My stupid fault.

Comment: Language features are often not that related to the .NET version, especially the latest ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expression bodied property accessors were added in c# 7.0, in c# 6.0 you can use expression body only for methods.
Auto property Initializers (`int Count {get;} = 1;`) are not to be confused with expression-bodied properties (`int Count {get => return 1;}`).

From [What's new in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members)

> C# 6 introduced expression-bodied members for member functions, and read-only properties.
>   C# 7 expands the allowed members that can be implemented as
>   expressions. In C# 7, you can implement constructors, finalizers,
>   **and get and set accessors on properties and indexers.**

(Emphasis mine)